# Displaying multiple trellis plots (from lattice) using grid.arrange nicely

Tags: r, lattice, gridextra

I am working with the `gridExtra` and `lattice` packages and wish to display multiple plots in the same plot window. I am working in an RMarkdown file and am testing my code by simply running the chunk.

```
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)
p1 = dotplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
grid.arrange(p1,p1,p1,p1)
```

[image]

As you can see, the plots are very difficult to read. I am having an awful time trying to figure out how to do this. How can I make these plots more readable? Adjusting the `heights` and `widths` argument in `grid.arrange` does not seem to do the trick:

I'm not sure if the correct solution lies in the `grid.arrange` function, the `dotplot` function, or the underlying trellis options (from `trellis.par.get)`, or if there is something that can be done to the plot window within my markdown file. I apologize as I am a beginner in visualizations with R, but I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: You can use `xyplot` in place of `dotplot`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to dig deeper into the `grid` engine to refine the positions on the plot. As an alternative, perhaps you can use the `plot.trellis` method that is available with the `lattice` package. The `position` argument allows you to specific the x and y extent of each grob. One simple way to get rid of excess white space is to overlap the plots slightly. The code below uses the variables xd and yd to provide the extent of overlap for the x and y directions, respectively.

```
# needed for plot.trellis() method
  library(lattice)

# midpoints and excess on either side of the midpoint
# these need to be adjusted for device size as well as plot details
  m <- 0.5 # midpoint of plot panel
  xd <- 0.04 # extra added or removed in X direction from midpoint 'm'
  yd <- 0.05 # extra added or removed in Y direction
 
# This could be coded as single loop but may be more apparent like this
  plot(p1, position = c(xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=m + xd, ymax=m + yd), more = TRUE)
  plot(p1, position = c(m - xd, 0, 1, m + yd), more = TRUE)
  plot(p1, position = c(0, m - yd, m + xd, 1), more = TRUE)
  plot(p1, position = c(m - xd, m - yd, 1, 1), more = FALSE)
```

[image: example plot with tighter placement]